# Should I provide plant food for an oak tree I am trying to raise?

Tags: trees

I am trying to raise an oak tree I planted from an acorn. I planted it behind a wall of trees, hoping it will prevail. But it doesn't really work, because in the summer it doesn't get much sun light.
So, I dug it out and put it in an pot on the window sill. The soil I took from my compost. It's doing fine. I water it regularly.
Now I am wondering if I should also give it "plant food".
I want to get it stronger before I put it outside in the pot, and take it back in in the winter.
No, I don't have another place to plant it. My property is smallish.

Comment: Not part of the question thus a comment: Do not take it inside in winter. Oaks are deciduous trees that need the resting/dormant phase.

Comment: @Stephie Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: I guess this is actually more a general question if house plants need addition nutrition. If plants are growing outside, they are where they are, and the only change might be from decomposing leaves etc. I never give my house plants more than water and they are doing fine.

Comment: What species of oak? The growth rates vary a lot, and some species (e.g. English oak) are slow growing but long lived (more than 500 years). An English oak in good conditions might only grow 6 inches per year for the first 10 years or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not give plant food to a tree sapling. If the plant food is too strong, you could damage the sapling. The soil probably has enough nutrients for the tree. Trees do not require tremendous amounts of nutrients.

Comment: Thank you. I put the pot (with holes in the bottom) outside.